# How to block file upload in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am an IT admin managing Windows endpoints in enterprise network. I want to prevent enterprise users from uploading files to their personal office 365 accounts with chrome, while allowing files to be uploaded for enterprise office 365 account. Is this doable via GPO policy, registry or chrome extension? Of course it will be even better if the solution works for all browsers including Firefox, Opera and Edge. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If your question isn't about Chrome extension *development* (it doesn't sound like you're looking to build your own) but rather about existing tools for that, StackOverflow might not be the best place to ask. You could consider sister sites, [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). If I'm wrong - you should probably edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: I know javascript, so I can write my extension if it works. Of course other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i decide to set up http/https filter in gateway and filter http requests based on request URL, enterprise account has different urls